# Solidity Assembly. Read struct from storage & delegatecall

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I'm using a low level delegatecall to forward my calls to a library but I'm not familiar enough with inline assemblyl to make it work.

```
contract BountyProxy {
  using BountyLibrary for BountyLibrary.Bounty;
  BountyLibrary.Bounty bounty;
  address impl;

  constructor(bytes32 _reference, address _issuer, uint _deadline, address _lib) public payable {
        impl = _lib;
        bounty.init(_reference, _issuer, _deadline);
  }

  function forward(bytes32 _sig, bytes _data) external payable {
    bytes memory data = _data;
    bytes4 sig = bytes4(_sig);
    address _impl = impl;
    require(_impl != address(0));
    assembly {

      let _message := mload(0x40) //find empty memory location
      mstore(_message, sig) //place sig at beginning of empty storage
      //add _bounty
      mstore(add(_message, 4), sload(bounty_slot))
      //add _data
      mstore(add(_message, 36), data)
      let size := returndatasize
      let result := delegatecall(gas, _impl, _message, msize, _message, size)
      //return data ??????
      returndatacopy(_message, 0, size)
      switch result
      case 0 {revert(_message, size) }
      default { return(_message, size) }
    }
  }

  function getBounty() external view returns (bytes32, address, uint, uint, uint, BountyLibrary.statusOptions) {
    return bounty.getBounty();
  }
}
```

The full code can be found in this fiddle: https://ethfiddle.com/sd1ATrDtjy
Additionally the migrations can be found here: https://gist.github.com/kyriediculous/d2286a8a580d28a3903395490b15bcaa

I need to (in this order) :

- load bytes4 sig into _message from memory
- load bounty (STRUCT) into _message from storage
- load bytes _data into _message
- Delegatecall with the new message
- Get return values

The contract & library works as proven by the getBounty() function I added. The forwarder is what I'm having trouble with.

- How do I load in the bounty struct from storage?
- How do I properly split my calldata at the first 4 bytes , copy it to memory and put the bounty struct in between?

It seems like the struct is unpacked when I call getStorageAt, do I have to repack it?

```
0x00
0x687474703a2f2f6170692e6269746275636b65742e636f6d2f33303433303430
0xe1bb4acb579f780cbaf21cef9ac3641b8e3fcd69
0x5b7eb10c
0x3334303330340000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
0x012a05f200
0x00
0x00
0x059ce9161d4fb0
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00
0x00
```

Please feel free to refer to stackexchange as well: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/57197/get-return-data-from-delegatecall

Many thanks.